# How to read Java class def from .class file?

Tags: java

I am writing Java application and I want to write some simple plugin system. I want to have base class Plugin. Other classes extends Plugin, these files are in some other directory out of class path.

```
public class Plugin {
    public Plugin() {
        //code
    }

    public void proc() {
        //code
    }
}
```

and class loader:

```
public class PluginLoader {
    private static final FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return Pattern.matches("^.*[a-zA-Z]*[.]class$", name);
        }
    };

    public static final String removeExtension(String str) {
        if (str == null)
            return null;
        int pos = str.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (pos == -1)
            return str;
        return str.substring(0, pos);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static LinkedList<Plugin> loadEffects(String path) {
        LinkedList<Plugin> result = new LinkedList<Plugin>();
        Plugin instance = null;
        File[] classesList = null;
        System.out.println("Searching in " + path);
        try {
            File classDir = new File(path);
            URL[] url = { classDir.toURI().toURL() };
            URLClassLoader urlLoader = new URLClassLoader(url);
            String filename;
            classesList = classDir.listFiles(filter);
            System.out.println(classesList.length + " class files found:");
            for (File file : classesList) {
                System.out.println("- " + file.getName());
            }
            for (File file : classesList) {
                filename = removeExtension(file.getName());
                if (filename.equals(".") || filename.equals("..") || filename.startsWith("."))
                    continue;
                if (filename.equals("Plugin")) {
                    System.err.println("File name is Plugin");
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println("Reading " + filename);
                instance = (Plugin) urlLoader.findClass(filename).getConstructor().newInstance();
                System.out.println("Adding: " + url + ", " + filename);
                result.push(instance);
            }
            urlLoader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This code causes **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: D:\test\PluginImpl/class (wrong name: test/PluginImpl)**. Plugin class is in D:\test.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling File#getAbsolutePath() which will include the entire path and the drive letter (`D:\`). The class name stored in the class does not match with the class name you provided so Java throws an error.

Try calling findClass with just the class name and it should work